# Why is SU(2) not the same group as T3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

Why is $S^3 = SU(2)$ not the same group as $ S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1 $?

It seems that, the $T^3$ torus is abelian, wheras $S^3$ is not. Is that enough?

Problem 2.6.5 from John Stillwell, Naive Lie Theory.

Comment: S^3 is simply connected but S^1 isn't.

Comment: Yes, that's enough. Ben's argument establishes that they aren't the same *Lie* group, but doesn't establish that they aren't the same abstract group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that, the $T^3$ torus is abelian, wheras $S^3$ is not. Is that enough?

Yes, that is enough to show they are not the same group
and not the same Lie group. As for groups, I'm sure you
know that two groups $G$ and $H$ are equivalent if and
only if there exists an group isomorphism
$f:G \rightarrow H$. Since $S^3$ is nonabelian while
$T^3$ is abelian, no such isomorphism exists. Next,
Lie groups $G$ and $H$ are equal if and only if there
exists a smooth group isomorphism $f$ from $G$ to $H$ whose
inverse is smooth. This smooth group isomorphism is,
in particular, a group isomorphism. But no group isomorphism
from $G$ to $H$ exists, so no smooth and smoothly invertible
group isomorphism from $G$ to $H$ exists. Hence the two Lie
groups are not equivalent.